# Are there any cases on record of an aircraft crashing into an occupied air traffic control tower?

Tags: air-traffic-control, accidents

Aircraft frequently<sup>1</sup> crash, or come close to crashing, from almost every cause imaginable, on or near airports, these being places where aircraft of all sizes take off and land and sleep with many other aircraft in close proximity, and where being a hundred feet above or below or to the left or right of where you should be has much worse consequences than it does up where the only things to hit are other aircraft (which are small targets which ATC does their best to keep at least five to ten hectofeet away from you vertically, and several miles away horizontally); this is why airports have specialised [ARFF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aircraft_rescue_and_firefighting) units, while your neighbourhood fire department probably doesn’t.

Usually (and hopefully, at least from the airport’s perspective), the only things that get damaged are the aircraft itself, one of the runways, and some grass, but aircraft [also occasionally](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/North_Central_Airlines_Flight_458) [crash into hangars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Air_Midwest_Flight_5481), and approach lights and ILS antennae are semiregular victims of errant aircraft.<sup>2</sup>  Surprisingly, though, I can’t seem to find any instances of an occupied ATC tower being hit by an aircraft, even though it’s a tall structure in the middle of an airport - are there any known cases of an aircraft crashing into an active tower, or have the controllers just been lucky so far?

---

<sup>1</sup>: Well, more frequently than they crash most other places, at least.

<sup>2</sup>: Which is why they’re made to be frangible (break apart harmlessly when struck); okay, *[usually](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_Airlines_Flight_1420)* frangible.

Comment: I did a search for "aircraft crash control tower" and found https://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-1204181/One-dead-seven-injured-plane-crashes-air-traffic-control-tower-Thailand.html straight away. Where did you search?

Comment: Slightly related-- a twin-engine aircraft crashed into an occupied "Flight Safety" company building in KICT a few years ago, causing several fatailities

Comment: I'm not sure I've ever seen the term "hectofeet" used anywhere ever

Comment: @GregHewgill: Mainly the NTSB's AAR database.  Feel free to write that up into an answer...

Comment: When I was jumping years ago a fellow skydiver managed to land in a solitary tree in the middle of an open field, so anything's possible.

Comment: I don't understand the downvote. This is a good question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a realistic or personal thing, just a wild curiosity, and these tend to distract, and not attract quality answers.

Comment: @Pheric The mouse-over says "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful". The comments show that basic research would have answered the question. And, arguably, it's not useful, either (but that seems kinda subjective).

Comment: @Harper wouldn't be wild curiosity if he was looking for accidents to research for a report on alternative airport layouts or something. We don't know why this question was asked.

Comment: @Pheric click the blue word "Sean" above.

Comment: @Harper fair enough.